# Grunt filerev / usemin doesn't update name when using alternate search path

Tags: php, wordpress, gruntjs

I am trying to create some grunt tasks for wordpress. Themes need root-relative urls (usually handled by php) so I am trying to use usemin's alternate search path to create the urls. It seems to break file revving. Current code:

```
<!-- build:css(/assets/css/style.min.css) /wp-content/themes/ees-theme/assets/css/style.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/style.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Working block:

```
<!-- build:css assets/css/style.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

it revs the file no problem. Not sure what I am doing wrong, although feel it must be to do with file paths.

I have tried changing / adding paths (quite randomly after a while) to see if anything works.

here is usemin / rev grunt code:

```
 useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= paths.dist %>/header.php','<%= paths.dist %>/footer.php'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= paths.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['concat', 'cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    filerev: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                algorithm: 'sha1',
                length: 3
            },
            src:  ['<%= paths.dist %>/assets/**/*.*', '!<%= paths.dist %>/assets/**/*.php'],
        }
    },
    usemin: {
        html: [
            //'<%= paths.dist %>/{,*/}*.php',
            '<%= paths.dist %>/header.php'
        ],
        css: ['<%= paths.dist %>/assets/css/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                './<%= paths.dist %>/',
                './<%= paths.dist %>/assets/**/*.*'
                ],
        }
    },
```